# How do I match a specific order of letters with python 2.x RE

Tags: python, regex, string, match

I want to match a specific order of letters with Python's Re module. For example, how could I match thing like

- bob
- ara
- gag

but not

- aaa
- bal

ie: I want one letter, then another, and then the first again.

For two different letters, I could just loop over all 650 possibilities. However, when matching larger strings, that becomes impossible (and isn't really nice anyways).

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex with capturing group, lookahead and a back-reference:

```
^([a-zA-Z])(?!\1)[a-zA-Z]\1$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBka56/6)

```
^                # line start
([a-zA-Z])       # match any letter and capture it as group #1
(?!\1)[a-zA-Z]   # match any letter but make sure it is not what have in group #1
\1               # match what we captured in capture group #1
$                # line end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `([a-zA-Z])(?!\1)[a-zA-Z]\1`

[image]